# Is there a way to get directly to the desired user for a specific Google service while using multiple sign-in?

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus, google-multi-login

I am permanently logged in as two users, Google Apps for domains and also my non-Google Apps Gmail account. This is what happens whenever I am using Google Apps for domains, and want to use other services, such as Google Plus: When I open the page it first takes me to the Google Apps logged in version - where I annoyingly need to switch users, using the drop-down menu.

Is there any way to navigate directly to Gmail logged in user?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to bookmark a Google calendar or inbox for a specific account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86559/354)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Gmail URL looks like this: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`. You might notice the `0`, which is the index of the first element in the array of accounts you have, or the default account. If you change it to `1`, it will automatically log you into the second account, and so on.

In modern browsers, when you log into your second Gmail account you should already be redirected to `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox` so you could simply bookmark that URL.

Comment: thanks, it made my day! starting from your answer, I looked closer at  **Google+** where its the same `https://plus.google.com/u/1/` 


For **Google Reader** the url structure is slightly different:  `http://www.google.com/reader/view/?at=<longIDstring>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the (apparently) undocumented `authuser` URL parameter to create your bookmarks. For instance:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=mypersonalaccount@gmail.com

https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=mycompanyaccount@example.com
```

This seems to work for Gmail, Calendar, Inbox, and presumably (most) other Google services. (At least those that support multi-login.)

Answer (score -1):

I use two browsers. I log into my personal Google/Gmail account in Firefox, and the corporate Google based accounts in Chrome.

The two browsers prevent the logging into multiple accounts from confusing the issue.

Comment: That's beside the question. But anyway, since you mentioned it, if you're using Chrome you don't even need to browsers, as you can have different user profiles in 2 windows of Chrome.