# Is it possible to bookmark a Google calendar or inbox for a specific account?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, google-account

I have a Google account for work, and another personal account.  I have on more than one occasion clicked the bookmark I made in my work folder and been confused by not seeing (e.g.) an important meeting on my calendar.

Only when I realized that Google treats the two calendars as identical resources (they have the same URL) did I understand what was going on.

Is there any way to correct this?  Is there any way to bookmark my work calendar(s) separately from my personal calendar(s)?  (Same with my e-mail?)

Comment: A related question on this site: [Can I form a direct URL to a particular Gmail account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18959/33787) – and another related question on SO: [How to get google calendar URL for specific logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70294622/1478931)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems to be an undocumented feature, but you can use the `authuser` URL parameter.

So, you can create bookmarks that will take you directly to the calendar for a specific account, like so:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/?authuser=mypersonalaccount@gmail.com

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/?authuser=mycompanyaccount@example.com
```

Gmail works similarly:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=mypersonalaccount@gmail.com

https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=mycompanyaccount@example.com
```

As does Google's Inbox by Gmail:

```
https://inbox.googl‌​e.com/?authuser=mypersonalaccount@gmail.com

https://inbox.googl‌​e.com/?authuser=mycompanyaccount@example.com
```

You may need to be logged in to both accounts using Google's multi-account feature, but my test with Google Chrome worked just great.

Comment: This also works with Drive. BTW you don't need the directory parts of the URLs, `calendar/` and `mail/`. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `authuser=0` for the first account signed in, `authuser=1` for the second, etc. [More info](https://superuser.com/a/619448/443564)

Comment: @wjandrea authuser=0 or =1 is dependent upon the order in which you sign-in, which will change over time.  So if you want a consistent bookmark (like "Personal Gmail") you'll want to use the email address instead of the number.

Comment: Confirmed this still works in 2021 for Calendar and Gmail, using https://calendar.google.com/?authuser=<me>@gmail.com and https://mail.google.com/?authuser=<me>@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with this

https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://calendar.google.com&Email=username@gmail.com

Works even when you are not loggen in.